# Как сделать что бы отображались символы в консоли?

Tags: c++

В консоли вместо символа показывает вопросительный знак.

cout << "A △ B (";
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какую библиотеку надо подключить или как починить эту проблему?

Comment: Использовать `wcout`?

Comment: Какая ОС, какая консоль? Обычно через cout можно нормально выводить только ascii символы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить Локаль. setlocale(), но в консоли могут отображаться только ASCII символы http://book.itep.ru/10/ascii.htm, можете так же попробовать изменить кодовую страницу с помощью функции SetConsoleCP();

Comment: Не стоит распространять дезинформацию про setlocale...

Comment: Кодовую страницу на греческую только ради буквы Дельта? А как русский потом выводить?

Comment: Вопрос был в том, как сделать так, чтоб в консоли показывался символ. Кстати когда вы хотите выводить русский, это тоже замена кодовой страницы на CP1251 - Кириллица. Ей богу, это обьясняют на первой паре Истории Информатики.

Comment: Насчет вывода русского, кодовую страницу можно менять сколько угодно. Хоть друг под другом, это не влияет на работу программы.

Comment: Вы законченный ответ то не дали, как вывести дельту? Если просто прописать `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Greek");SetConsoleOutputCP(1253);` это не работает. Видимо, нужно еще сам исходник перекодировать в эту греческую кодировку, а это уже куда менее удобно. История информатики это прекрасно, но у нас принято давать актуальные ответы.

Comment: Я написал, какие символы используются в консоли и что если очень надо, можно поменять кодировку, на какой ответ еще расчитываете? Давайте закончим дискуссию. Это глупо.